# Facebook won't let me recover my account via SMS [Facebook is acting weird]

Tags: facebook, account-recovery

I have a Facebook account for 6 years. My phone number and e-mail are registered and confirmed in my account. 2 years ago I bought a new phone and logged into my account. 2 years later (yesterday) I bought a new device. My facebook is active on my old phone. I want to sign in on my new phone. But I forgot my account password. I'm trying to recover my account, there is an email recovery option, but it was an email address I didn't use and I don't remember the password. The main problem is, I have a phone number registered in my account and it was confirmed. But when trying to recover my account **it doesn't offer recovery by SMS option**. So even though my phone number is registered, facebook doesn't even show this option. It only allows me to recover my account via email. While I was trying to reset my password on the device that I have been logged into for 2 years, I needed to be able to reset my password easily because facebook trusts this device. But it defines the device that has been logged in for 2 years as "We dont recognize your device".

Comment: Here is Facebooks link to [what to do if you can't reset Facebook password because can't access the email on my account[(https://www.facebook.com/help/132243923516844/)

Comment: This does not fully explain the problem. My phone number is active and i can find my account by searching phone. But when I go to https://facebook.com/login/identify, Facebook does not offer the phone recover option even though my phone number is registered and confirmed.

Comment: I understand @firslord however is very difficult to assist you with a problem of this nature.  You will need to jump through Facebook's steps.  Here is another Facebook link that might provide you with different approaches. [Fix a Login Problem](https://www.facebook.com/help/283100488694834/?helpref=hc_fnav)

Comment: Unfortunately none of the options here are working. I contacted my facebook partner yesterday. He also did not understand how this problem happened. He even asked me for a screen recording video and could not get out of it. The account must be able to be recover with a confirmed phone number. If you want you can see username: ilyas.bayramoglu.5